# MySQL syntax error on image upload

Tags: asp.net, mysql

I have a small file upload on a website that is supposed to upload a selected image and place it in a mysql database. The image is stored as type a varbinary (8000 length). My code is:

```
 Public Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    If fileupload1.HasFile Then

        Dim pimage As Byte() = fileupload1.FileBytes
        Dim pid As String = partnum.Text.ToString
        Dim sConnection As String = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; SERVER=localhost; DATABASE=inteva; UID=root; PASSWORD=root; OPTION=3"
        Dim connectme As New OdbcConnection(sConnection)
        Dim sInsertInto As String = "INSERT INTO images(serial, image1) VALUES(?pserial, ?ppimage)"
        Dim com As New OdbcCommand(sInsertInto, connectme)

        com.Parameters.Add("pserial", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = pid
        com.Parameters.Add("?ppimage", OdbcType.VarBinary).Value = pimage

        connectme.Open()
        Dim result As Integer = com.ExecuteNonQuery()
        connectme.Close()

        If result > 0 Then
            lblimageup.Text = "Image saved."
        End If

    Else
        lblimageup.Text = "Please select an image file"

    End If
End Sub
```

When I execute this, I get a sytax error as follows:

```
ERROR [42000] [MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver][mysqld-5.6.11]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'pserial, 'ÿØÿá/þExif\0\0MM\0*\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0’\0\0\0\0   \0\' at line 1
```

I can't seem to find any syntax error. Any ideas? Could it be the image file have something in it breaking the syntax?

Answer (score 1):

try with below code, use `@paramName` in both `SQL` and `Patameters.Add`

```
Dim sInsertInto As String = "INSERT INTO images(serial, image1) VALUES (@pserial, @ppimage)"
Dim com As New OdbcCommand(sInsertInto, connectme)

com.Parameters.Add("@pserial", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = pid
com.Parameters.Add("@ppimage", OdbcType.VarBinary).Value = pimage
```

Comment: This corrected the syntax error, but now I get an error saying "serial cannot be null" as it is my primary key in this database. There is a value being passed to pid, but I guess the parameter isn't picking this up. Why not?

Comment: @ECrux do you have value for pid? what id the data type in db?

Comment: I do have the value in the textbox. The data type is varchar

Comment: @ECrux can you generate the create table script for your table and update the question with that? and also debug and see the value you get as pid before `ExecuteNonQuery`

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look consistent; I think you wanted to do `"?pserial"`.

```
com.Parameters.Add("pserial", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = pid
com.Parameters.Add("?ppimage", OdbcType.VarBinary).Value = pimage
```

Comment: Ah, sorry I pasted the wrong param. I had already corrected the param to ?pserial. I still have the same error.